# Ubuntu, How to boot into CLI only from LiveCD without getting into desktop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

so i wanted to perform backup and restore my virtual ubuntu system with rsync. Now, i ald backed up the whole system into my usb flash drive. Then, i intentionally destroy my system by deleting the boot folder. Now i need to get to the CLI or terminal from my liveCD image which i ald loaded. But i dont kno how to get into just the CLI. There's only option to install or try ubuntu. I try to follow a tutorial on YT which used Arch Linux, and since i dont have arch linux, i try to practice it on Ubuntu instead.

Answer (score 2):

Boot the liveCD, wait until it gives you the option to install or try Ubuntu, then hit the `<ESC>` key twice (escape). It should prompt you that you are leaving the graphical environment.

If that doesn't work, click 'Try Ubuntu', wait for it to boot, and press `<CTRL>` + `<ALT>` + `<F2>`.

The credentials for the liveCD are 'ubuntu' and a blank password.

For the second method, you can return to the graphical environment with `<CTRL>` + `<ALT>` + `<F7>`.